# Does PriorityQueue's remove method rearrange the heap?

Tags: java, sorting, queue, compare, heap

When the `remove` method is called on a `PriorityQueue` object in java, the head of the heap is removed. To put the new minimum element at the head, are any sorting operations done on the rest of the heap? For example, is the `compareTo` method called when `remove` is called?

Apologies if this is in the docs, I can't find it anywhere. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just checked the documentation and there wasn't anything specified about this.  I'm curious to hear the answer!

Comment: Thanks, glad to know I'm not missing anything too obvious!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `PriorityQueue` is implemented as a balanced binary heap implemented as an array. When an element is removed, the heap has to reorder itself to keep the order of the heap.

The proof is in the comments

```
/**
 * Priority queue represented as a balanced binary heap: the two
 * children of queue[n] are queue[2*n+1] and queue[2*(n+1)].  The
 * priority queue is ordered by comparator, or by the elements'
 * natural ordering, if comparator is null: For each node n in the
 * heap and each descendant d of n, n <= d.  The element with the
 * lowest value is in queue[0], assuming the queue is nonempty.
 */
private transient Object[] queue;
```

Also in the class javadoc

> Implementation note: this implementation provides **O(log(n)) time for
>   the enqueing and dequeing methods (offer, poll, remove() and add)**;
>   linear time for the remove(Object) and contains(Object) methods; and
>   constant time for the retrieval methods (peek, element, and size).

For `remove()`, for example, you remove the root of the Heap. You take the last element, ie. right-most leaf at the last level of the binary tree, and put it as root and make sift down until it finds its place (based on `Comparator`). That takes at worst `O(log n)` time.

Comment: While I agree that this is what *needs* to happen, is there anything in the documentation that justifies that this is what *actually* happens?

Comment: @templatetypedef When it states that it is implemented as a Heap, that reordering necessarily needs to happen. Otherwise, it is not a Heap. you can go through the rest of the source code for implementation details.

Comment: @templatetypedef, http://goo.gl/cCKOt3 is the source code for `remove(Object o)`, which actually calls `indexOf(o)` and `removeAt(i)`, where the former does an O(n) search, and the latter an O(log(n)) sift operation.

Comment: @lcn- A particular implementation of `remove` doesn't necessarily guarantee anything about the required behavior, but thanks for the link!

Answer (score 1):

It depends. If you are `remove`ing the last element in the array that backs the `PriorityQueue`, then no resorting will be done. If you `remove` any other element, it will reorder its elements (`siftUp` and `siftDown`):

```
public boolean remove(Object o) {
    int i = indexOf(o);
    if (i == -1)
        return false;
    else {
        removeAt(i);
        return true;
    }
}

private E removeAt(int i) {
    assert i >= 0 && i < size;
    modCount++;
    int s = --size;
    if (s == i) // removed last element
        queue[i] = null;
    else {
        E moved = (E) queue[s];
        queue[s] = null;
        siftDown(i, moved);
        if (queue[i] == moved) {
            siftUp(i, moved);
            if (queue[i] != moved)
                return moved;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```